# Backbone.js - Rendering array from View without making a loop in the template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm loading all posts for a page using backbone. And Loading comments for a post when clicked on the "Get all comments" link. I'm getting all comments from an Ajax call.

```
Social.Views.StreamsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

    comment_template: JST['streams/comment'],

    comment_displayall: function(data, post_id) {
      this.$("#comments").html(this.comment_template({
        comment: data // Here data is array
      }));
    }
});
```

I have **comment.jst.ejs file** which **has a loop now but I have to put it in view**

```
  <% _.each(comment.comments,function(comment){ %> // I want to get rid of this Line
 <div class="stream_comment">
   <div class="stream_commentphoto">
    <a><img src="<%= comment.actor.thumbnail.url %>"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="stream_comm-content">
    <a href="#"><h5><%= comment.actor.displayName %></h5> </a>
    <p><%= comment.content %></p>
   </div>
 </div>
<%}%>
```

How can i get rid of the loop inside Comment template, by adding the loop in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
comment_displayall: function(data, post_id) {

    //clear any existing comments
    var $comments = this.$("#comments").empty();

    //render each comment separately and append to the view
    _.each(data.comments, function(comment) {
        $comments.append(this.comment_template({comment:comment});      
    }, this);
}
```

And simply remove the loop construct (first and last line) of your template.

/Code sample not tested